# Как настроить стандартный код в Clion?

Tags: c++, clion

Как в Clion ( OS X 10.14) установить стандартный код для cpp.-шников, который будет в файле после его создания ? Не нашел где находится эта настройка, она должна быть по любому

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the Settings/Preferences dialog (⌘,), select Editor | File and Code Templates.
On the Includes tab, click the Create  button and specify the name, file extension, and body. 
Apply the changes and close the dialog.

Comment: Это русскоязычный сайт. Пожалуйста, напишите ваш ответ на русском языке.